# Ansible. Link for variables in group vars

Tags: ansible

I have duplicated vars in my group_vars file. They need for different roles.
For example:

```
games:
  - name: game1
    host: game1.com
    mongodb_user:
      - {db: "mydb", user: "user1", pass: "pass1" }
  - name: game2
    host: game2.com
    mongodb_user:
      - {db: "mydb", user: "user2", pass: "pass2" }

mongodb_users:
  - {db: "mydb", user: "user1", pass: "pass1" }
  - {db: "mydb", user: "user2", pass: "pass2" }
```

Can I use something like links to declare mongodb_users?

Comment: Please read the YAML documentation on [anchors](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html##id2785586)) and [aliases](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2786196)

Answer (score 2):

Since this is YAML, you can use YAML [anchor](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html##id2785586) and [alias](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2786196) nodes.

```
mongodb_users:
  - &user1 {db: "mydb", user: "user1", pass: "pass1" }
  - &user2 {db: "mydb", user: "user2", pass: "pass2" }

games:
  - name: game1
    host: game1.com
    mongodb_user:
      - *user1
  - name: game2
    host: game2.com
    mongodb_user:
      - *user2
```

You can see [here](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/?yaml=mongodb_users%3A%0A%20%20-%20%26user1%20%7Bdb%3A%20%22mydb%22%2C%20user%3A%20%22user1%22%2C%20pass%3A%20%22pass1%22%20%7D%0A%20%20-%20%26user2%20%7Bdb%3A%20%22mydb%22%2C%20user%3A%20%22user2%22%2C%20pass%3A%20%22pass2%22%20%7D%0A%0Agames%3A%0A%20%20-%20name%3A%20game1%0A%20%20%20%20host%3A%20game1.com%0A%20%20%20%20mongodb_user%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20-%20*user1%0A%20%20-%20name%3A%20game2%0A%20%20%20%20host%3A%20game2.com%0A%20%20%20%20mongodb_user%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20-%20*user2&type=json) how aliases will get resolved.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the value of variables to other variables. 
So you should be able to write something like this:

```
mongodb_users:
  - "{{ games[0].mongodb_user }}"
  - "{{ games[1].mongodb_user }}"
```

Comment: Can I have something like loop, to write it in one string?